# WebSocket java client issue - (Working Fine from Browser)

Tags: websocket, tomcat8, java-ee-7, java-websocket

I am trying to write a java client for the WebSocket using @ClientEndpoint.
The Server end point is working fine for sure as I am able to connect to it via browser (JavaScript clients). However whenever I am trying to connect to it using java client I get the below exception which doesn't reveal much about itself.
Just to add on to info the same project is working fine on my personal laptop. However it fails at my work system (perhaps some firewalls and all but in that case I think it should have failed for as javascript client as well ) .

**Technology stack : Java 7, Tomcat 8 / Weblogic**

**EDIT**
Just to update, using **tyrus standalone jar** I am now able to connect to WebSocket even from java client. But issue remains same when I connect through Apache Tomcat 8.

Exeption :

```
java.io.IOException: ConnectEx failed
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.access$200(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:43)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$ConnectTask.run(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:235)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implConnect(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:382)
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.connect(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:198)
at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.client.proxy.Direct.connect(Direct.java:19)
at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.client.AIOWsClientSocket.openChannel(AIOWsClientSocket.java:151)
at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.client.AIOWsClientSocket.connect(AIOWsClientSocket.java:106)
at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.client.AIOWsClientContainer.openClientSocket(AIOWsClientContainer.java:41)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$1.run(ClientManager.java:426)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:620)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:351)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:187)
at MovieEventSocketClient.<init>(MovieEventSocketClient.java:22)
at HelloWorldServiceTest.initializeWebSocket(HelloWorldServiceTest.java:21)
at HelloWorldServiceTest.sendMessageOverSocket(HelloWorldServiceTest.java:27)
at HelloWorldServiceTest.main(HelloWorldServiceTest.java:37) 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: ConnectEx failed
at MovieEventSocketClient.<init>(MovieEventSocketClient.java:25)
at HelloWorldServiceTest.initializeWebSocket(HelloWorldServiceTest.java:21)
at HelloWorldServiceTest.sendMessageOverSocket(HelloWorldServiceTest.java:27)
at HelloWorldServiceTest.main(HelloWorldServiceTest.java:37) 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ConnectEx failed
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.access$200(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:43)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$ConnectTask.run(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:235)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implConnect(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:382)
at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.connect(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:198)
at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.client.proxy.Direct.connect(Direct.java:19)
at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.client.AIOWsClientSocket.openChannel(AIOWsClientSocket.java:151)
at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.client.AIOWsClientSocket.connect(AIOWsClientSocket.java:106)
at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.client.AIOWsClientContainer.openClientSocket(AIOWsClientContainer.java:41)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$1.run(ClientManager.java:426)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:620)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:351)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:187)
at MovieEventSocketClient.<init>(MovieEventSocketClient.java:22)
... 3 more
```

Here is  the code which is throwing the eerror

```
@ClientEndpoint public class MovieEventSocketClient {   public MovieEventSocketClient(URI endpointURI) {        try {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider
                .getWebSocketContainer();
        container.connectToServer(MovieEventSocketClient.class, endpointURI);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone ??? Anything??